# akka-kryo-serialization ClassNotFoundException: scala.Enumeration$Val

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, kryo

Sometimes when updating a dependency version for my project, when I would run the project I would get the following error:

```
ERROR 09:31:34:241 apply$mcV$sp - Class could not be loaded and/or registered: scala.Enumeration$Val 
ERROR 09:31:34:247 apply$mcV$sp - exception caught during akka-kryo-serialization startup: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Enumeration$Val
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

I usually got lucky and was able to fix this by tweaking the versions of my dependencies.

Until I updated my akka version from 2.3.6 to 2.3.12, specifically akka-contrib which contains akka-cluster, akka-remote and akka-peristance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was actually occurring during the transition between akka 2.3.8 and 2.3.9. Looking at the change log, I found that between these two versions the Scala version was upgraded from 2.11.4 to 2.11.5.

My project was building on scala 2.11.4. Upgrading to 2.11.5 fixed the problem.

I couldn't find any help online for this, and lost a couple days trying to figure this out. I'm hoping that this will help someone else out.

Comment: you'll see that for me this was happening under some very specific conditions (migrating from akka 2.3.8 to 2.3.9 with scala version explicitly set to 2.11.4). I would imagine it unlikely that you would have the exact same conditions over two years later.

If you want to open up a Stack Overflow question and link it here, I could take a stab at it. What would probably be the most helpful is if you provided that stack trace and possibly a dependency graph.

Comment: i am using 2.11.11 Scalaversion, my akka version is 2.5.6, kryo version 4.0.1 and akka-kryo-serialization version is 0.5.0. 

Stack trace :  ERROR spatcher-3 [-] c.r.a.s.k.KryoSerializer(akka://test) - Class could not be loaded and/or registered: scala.Enumeration$Val 
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Enumeration$Val
 ERROR spatcher-3 [-] c.r.a.s.k.KryoSerializer(akka://test) - exception caught during akka-kryo-serialization startup: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Enumeration$Val

Comment: I think the information you would need to give me in order to help you is really going to require a new SO Question. I would recommend writing out the questions, include what you included in the above comment, and possibly your sbt file and a [dependency graph with filterScalaLibrary := false](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph). On a hunch, I would suspect that at least one of those libraries is built against Scala 2.12 instead of 2.11 and is not compatible. Another issue might be that Kryo 0.5.0 is built against akka 2.4, so it might not work with Akka 2.5.